# Word For: Didn't Find Anything Wrong

Tags: single-word-requests

Working on some software, in the moderation we are using the word "ignore" for reported/flagged topics by users, but we didn't see anything wrong with what was reported. I don't really want to use the word ignore, because it sounds like an individual action rather than a group action.

Choosing to "ignore" a flagged post, makes that post invisible to all moderators. What are some other terms that cane be used in place of "ignore".

Comment: Doesn't the ELU Stack Exchange Review have a "Skip" option when the reviewer looks at a question but doesn't want to accept or make changes? Would "Skip" work in your situation?

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing enough about your software what about something like "Reviewed" or "Acknowledged"?  That way other moderators would know that certain moderators have seen the flag but found no foul?  @ChristopherE's "duck" phrase made me think of the poker phrase "pass" - to refrain from calling or betting when it is your turn to act.

Answer (score 2):

Bypass, disregard, shelve, and my favorite: duck.

Answer (score 2):

The users have *offered* reports and flags for the moderators to consider.

If the reports and flags are found to be without basis, their offers will be **declined**.

I think "decline" might be preferred to terms like "refuse", "reject", "ignore", etc, because it is generally considered to be more polite and respectful (which is obviously very important in a group activity like moderation).